# Use dropdown menu to print different ggplotly plots in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-markdown

I have a series of data with this format:

| GeneFam | s0 | Prev | Yvar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fam_VO056_k119_707118_2 | -2.94891455 | 1.897019 | Latitude_c |
| fam_VO118_k119_1069373_4 | -2.63244195 | 1.897019 | Latitude_c |
| fam_VO015_k119_739705_2 | -2.54050825 | 1.897019 | Aridity_Index_v3 |
| fam_VO203_k119_389361_1 | -1.25734198 | 4.336043 | MAT_wc2 |
| fam_VO036_k119_254678_4 | -1.15872311 | 1.897019 | MAT_wc2 |

Up to 13 different values for `Yvar`.

I am trying to plot 13 plots, one for each `Yvar` value, with `GeneFam` in x axis, `s0` in y axis, and bars filled by `Prev` gradient:

```
ple_wts <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x = s0, y = reorder(GeneFam, s0), fill = Prev)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("skyblue", "dodgerblue3", "brown1", "firebrick4")) +
  facet_wrap(~Yvar, scales = "free")
```

But I want to plot them interactively, using plotly or something similar, so each `Yvar` facet appears individually when selecting it from a dropdown menu.

I am working in Rmarkdown and I want the output to be an html. The initial markdown parameters are:

```
---
title: "<span style='font-size: 25px'><b>Something</b></span>"
subtitle: "<span style='font-size: 22px'><u>Something 2</u></span>"
author: "Myname"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d/%m/%Y")`'
output:
  rmdformats::material:
    highlight: kate
    self_contained: yes
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 8
    fig_width: 12
    thumbnails: false
    lightbox: true
---
```

How can I achieve this?

**Note**: *It does not need to be a facet-based plot, it can also be a list of ggplots if needed*.

Comment: I would use a carousel (slideshow) with the **swipeR** package. You can select the plot with bullets, not a dropdown menu.

Comment: I tried with the sample command they have at https://github.com/stla/swipeR. The carousel shows the navigation arrows but the plot frame is always blank...

Answer (score 1):

One solution using `plotly` package:

```
library(plotly)

my_colors <- c("skyblue", "dodgerblue3", "brown1", "firebrick4") |> 
  col2rgb() |> 
  t() |> 
  rgb(maxColorValue = 255)


# plot
mydata |> 
  plot_ly(
    x = ~s0, 
    y = ~GeneFam,
    color = ~Prev,
    colors = my_colors,
    type = "bar",
    transforms = list(
      list(
        type = "filter",
        target = ~Yvar,
        operation = "=",
        value = unique(mydata$Yvar)
      )
    )
  ) |> 
  layout(
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        x = 1.5,
        y = 1.2,
        type = "dropdown",
        active = 0,
        buttons = lapply(unique(mydata$Yvar),
                         function(x) list(method = "restyle",
                                          args = list("transforms[0].value", x),
                                          label = x)
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

[image]

##### data

```
mydata <- read.table(text="GeneFam  s0  Prev    Yvar
fam_VO056_k119_707118_2 -2.94891455 1.897019    Latitude_c
fam_VO118_k119_1069373_4    -2.63244195 1.897019    Latitude_c
fam_VO015_k119_739705_2 -2.54050825 1.897019    Aridity_Index_v3
fam_VO203_k119_389361_1 -1.25734198 4.336043    MAT_wc2
fam_VO036_k119_254678_4 -1.15872311 1.897019    MAT_wc2", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you, nice solution! But the problem is that the X and Y axes are always showing the same scales and values, which is inconvenient since I have hundreds of different GeneFam values per Yvar category, and the s0 scale per category is also very different. Could be the axes updated with this method?

Comment: @ALG if colors aren't important, one way you can try is to remove the argument `color = ~Prev`. This should scale the axes automatically based on your filter variable.

Comment: I tried it, and without the `color = ~Prev` argument the x axis does update, but the Y axis keeps showing every GeneFam even if no value exists for that Yvar value (just like it happens to you as well)